# cassandra snapshot restore on different cluster on missing schema

Tags: cassandra, backup

I have snapshot backup from cassandra cluster 1, and need to restore the same on cassandra cluster 2. Is it possible to do so, without having schema?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra table-schema details will be stored as meta data in system keyspaces.

Cassandra snapshot just creates a copy of sstables for the requested keyspace/column_familes. So to restore the snapshot, you need to explicitly create the schema in destination cluster.